# Why does \usepackage[inline]{asymptote} cause \ASYalign error?

Tags: errors, asymptote

In inline Asymptote, I can use packages like so:

```
usepackage("amsfonts");
label("$\mathbb R$", (0,0));
```

Generally, this works well. However, running `latexmk` on this:

```
usepackage("myPersonalPackage");
label("$\mathbb R$", (0,0));
```

causes an `Undefined control sequence. l.2 \ASYalign` error. (My personal package loads a bunch of packages, including the `amsfonts` package, so it's not an issue with the `\mathbb`.)

In fact, when I use vimtex's compiler (I'm not 100% clear what it is, but I think it's some form of `latexmk`), I get the following errors:

```
  1 test.aux|3 error| Undefined control sequence. \bbl@cs                                            
  2 test.aux|3 error| LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
  3 test-1.tex|13 error| Undefined control sequence. \ASYalign
  4 test-1.tex|13 error| Undefined control sequence.
```

I understand that `\ASYalign` is used when labeling things, and playing around with my own package shows me that the issue is that my style file automatically loads `\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}`. (Actually, the inline option isn't necessary to break things; `\usepackage{asymptote}` causes the same errors, assuming I load the inline option in the tex document itself.)

I was just wondering what it is about the Asymptote package which causes this error (and also what this `bbl@cs` error is; I couldn't figure it out since the only thing in my aux file is "`\relax`").

A few separate notes, if anybody has time:

1. Running vimtex's compiler twice often fixes things, whereas running `latexmk` twice doesn't do anything.
2. I've heard that removing the `test-1.tex` file will help, but it only sometimes works.
3. Does anyone have any suggested workarounds that don't require me to manually load Asymptote onto each tex file? (It's okay if not; it's not like it's that much work, since I use a snippet anyway to start tex files.)
4. Alternatively, does anyone know how to pass options in the `usepackage("PACKAGE")` command in Asymptote? If so, I can just do something like `usepackage("myPersonalPackage","skipAsy");` instead.

Comment: From [`asy` docs, p.53](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote.pdf):

The routine `void usepackage(string s, string options="");`
provides a convenient abbreviation for
`texpreamble("\usepackage["+options+"]{"+s+"}");`
that can be used for importing LaTeX packages.

Comment: Oh, that's great! I don't know if you want, but if you just make that an answer and nobody has a better one, I can just give you the bounty? Since I guess the 50 points would otherwise just go to waste

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from comment.

From [`asy` docs, p.53](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/asymptote.pdf):

The routine

```
void usepackage(string s, string options="");
```

provides a convenient abbreviation for

```
texpreamble("\usepackage["+options+"]{"+s+"}");
```

that can be used for importing LaTeX packages.